# How to create two diffrent apps from same android source code

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want to create 2 diffrent versions of my app so that both of them can reside on the same device, i need to somehow trick the apk installer that it would think that those apps are not the same and will let me install both of them at the same time.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the package name in the AndroidManifest.xml of one of the apps; this is the key Android uses to identify an application.

While it's possible to modify the manifest of an APK after it's been built, it's not always reliable.

Comment: but then im gonna have to change all my packages prefixes right?

Comment: The term "package" is a little overloaded in this context, so it's not clear what you're asking. If you mean the Java source package, no, they do not have to change at all. Android uses the package as defined in the AndroidManifest to determine apk uniqueness; that must change. If you believe that requires a Java package name change due to references to your Activities/etc., know that the manifest can refer to these by their (fixed) fully qualified name, rather than just their suffix, freeing you from needing to change them to continue to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gradle to build and manage dependancies. You can create flavours of your application (differents versions with differents configurations for exemple).

In your build.gradle :

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        versionCode 10
    }

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            packageName "com.example.flavor1"
            versionCode 20
        }

        flavor2 {
            packageName "com.example.flavor2"
            minSdkVersion 14
        }
    }
}
```

More informations :
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants